# Can Cosmos SQL Java upsertDocument method return null?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm wondering if it's possible for the Java `documentClient.upsertDocument` method to return null?  I don't see it in the documentation for this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.documentclient.upsertdocument?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Why? Can't you just not assign the return value from the method and ignore it?

Comment: Because I was wondering if it returns null.  I'm aware there's ways to handle it when you don't know.

Comment: Just assign it to var data type.